# Keycloak API always returns 401

Tags: https, keycloak, access-token, unauthorized

I'm trying to interact with Keycloak via its REST API. I have the master realm and the default admin user, and a test realm. Firstly, I get an access token for the admin account and test realm:

```
let data = {
    grant_type : 'password',
    client_id : 'test-realm',
    username : 'admin',
    password : 'admin'
};
let headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};
axios.post(
    'https://someurl.com:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token',
    qs.stringify(data),
    headers
)
```

That works ok. Then I try to make a call to create a user (or do anything else) and I get a 401 unauthorized error:

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`
};
data = {
    rep: {
        email: "test@email.com",
        username: "test@email.com"
    },
    path: 'test-realm'
};
axios.post('https://someurl.com:8080/auth/admin/realms/test-realm/users',
    qs.stringify(data),
    headers
)
```

Is that not the correct way to include the token? Is the access token the one you use for authenticating other API calls? Shouldn't the admin account's token work for authenticating calls to other clients with the master realm? Would it be some setting in the master realm that I have to change in the admin console? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I got same problem while using SpringBoot. This SO thread helped me to figure out the issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57477407/spring-app-with-keycloak-returns-401-error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is that not the correct way to include the token?

This is a correct way.

You just do something incorrectly.
Please, refer for an example from `keycloak-request-token` Node.js module:

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-request-token/blob/master/index.js#L43

You use

```
client_id : 'test-realm'
```

but there is

```
client_id: 'admin-cli'
```

there.

Also, to create a user, you should use

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

You can refer for Node.js examples of Keycloak REST API here:

https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example/blob/master/lib/adminClient.js

Examples of other useful stuff like:

- custom login
- storing Keycloak token in the cookies
- centralized permission middleware

can be found in the same project: [keycloak-nodejs-example](https://github.com/v-ladynev/keycloak-nodejs-example)

Comment: Thanks, that adminClient.js works! I just used their functions and use the keycloak-admin-client NPM module and I can create users and delete them, etc.

Comment: it works, but why I cannot use another client?

Comment: Umm, I have tried using a confidential flow with a custom client and it worked, but not with public

Answer (score 17):

I got a 401 error because I generated the offline token by using http://localhost:8080 and then I tried to request the api by using http://keycloak:8080 which is not allowed. Unfortunately the log doesn't tell you that.

To debug JWT tokens I recommend https://jwt.io/

Comment: Thank you that's it

Comment: We ran into this issue, I'm guessing your keycloak:8080 is a containerized keycloak. Turns out you can use it if you enable Frontend_Url, but depending how you do that the path may drop /auth/ on your redirect urls etc.

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-containers/blob/master/server/README.md#specify-frontend-base-url

Comment: Everyday heroes still exist ..Thank you Tobias!

Answer (score 7):

my problem was that client authentication was set to true , once i changed it to false it worked
[image]

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by enabling the below "Service Accounts Enabled" button under Settings for admin-cli

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue and solved it by making sure that there is no more than 1 minute between the first and the second API request. So, if you are doing this manually (2 curl requests), the token may expire and you may get error 401. Nevertheless, you should use admin-cli as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I came this issue recently and after struggling for a while i figured. using a realm name containing white spaces will trigger 401 unauthorized error when interacting with via SDKs or API.

IN SUMMARY:
change:  realm name
to:      realm-name

Comment: This advice is not helpful when operating e.g. two realms at once. I use keycloak for multiple applications and have one realm per application.

Comment: First day with Keycloak, I spent hours hitting a wall until I found this.