# Spring app with Keycloak returns 401 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, keycloak

I'm trying to access a Spring App via Keycloak, but I always get a 401 Unauthorized error. Basically I have a chat module that works fine on its own, but once I add Keycloak I'm unable to access the app due to that 401 error.
I've followed about 3 tutorials that showed similar things to what I've done, and I still have no idea what I've done wrong.

Here's my app's config :

```
keycloak: 
    enabled: true
    realm: myReal
    resource: myReal-api
    public-client: true
    bearer-only: true
    auth-server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
    credentials:
      secret: 82eXXXXX-3XXX-4XXX-XXX7-287aXXXXXXXX
    principal-attribute: preferred_username
    cors: true
```

From `localhost:port/` I have a first interface (with no Keycloak safety) that has a link to my service, which is `localhost:port/index/{topicName}` . Now when I click on that link, I'm supposed to get the Keycloak authentication screen, but I get a 401 error instead.

I've checked the header of my request, adding a HttpServletRequest as a parameter to my `displayMessage` method, and I actually could display the access_token and the X-Auth-Token in my IDE's console. But it seems like when I follow that link, it sends the request without the token.

Here are my controller methods (my Controller class is annotated with `@Controller`:

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/")
    public String index() {
        return "external";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/index/{topicName}",
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String displayMessages(Model model, 
            @PathVariable String topicName) {       

            //HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

            //headers.set("Authorization", request.getHeader("Authorization"));
            //header = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            //System.out.println(" T O K E N "+request.getHeader("X-Auth-Token"));

            projectServiceImpl.findByName(topicName);
            List<Message> messages = messageServiceImpl.findAllMessagesByProjectName(topicName);
            model.addAttribute("topic", topicName);
            model.addAttribute("message",messages);

            return "index";
    }
```

My Keycloak config file is inspired from the tuto's I've read, so there might be a mistake in there that I don't know about (not sure what the difference between methods `access` and `hasRole` is) :

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
        basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class,
        excludeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(
                type = FilterType.REGEX, 
                pattern = "org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager"))
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() { //replace HttpSessionStrategy
        return HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver.xAuthToken();
    }

    //Registers the KeycloakAuthenticationProvider with the authentication manager.
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        try {
            SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
            grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");
            grantedAuthorityMapper.setConvertToUpperCase(true);

            KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
            keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);

            auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider());

        } catch(Exception ex)  {
            logger.error("SecurityConfig.configureGlobal: " + ex);

        }

         /*try {
                KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
                keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
                auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
            }catch(Exception ex){
                logger.error("SecurityConfig.configureGlobal: " +ex);
            }*/
    }

    //Load Keycloak properties from service config-file
    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    //Defines the session authentication strategy.
    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        //Public or Confidential application keycloak/OpenID Connect client
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
        //Bearer mode only keycloak/OpenID Connect client without keycloak session -> stateless behavior
        //return new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
        //BEGIN
            //USER -done to be tested

            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/index**").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/").access("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/").access("hasAnyAuthority('ADMIN','MANAGER','EXPERT','STANDARD')")



            .anyRequest().authenticated() 

            .and()
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            //BEGIN Login/Logout
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()//.successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler) //
            .and()
            .logout()//.clearAuthentication(true) //Add .clearAuthentication(true) to logout()
                //.logoutUrl("/custom-logout")
                .addLogoutHandler(keycloakLogoutHandler())
                //.addLogoutHandler(new LogoutHandlerImpl())
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .permitAll();
            //END Login/Logout

        //BEGIN Session
        http
        .sessionManagement()
            //.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS) //BY default IF_REQUIRED
            .maximumSessions(1)
                .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(false) // if true generate an error when user login after reaching maximumSession (SessionAuthenticationStrategy rejected the authentication object / SessionAuthenticationException: Maximum sessions of 1 for this principal exceeded)
                //.expiredUrl("/auth/login")
                .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry());   



    }

     @Bean
     @Scope(scopeName = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
     public AccessToken accessToken() {
         HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
         return ((KeycloakSecurityContext) ((KeycloakAuthenticationToken) request.getUserPrincipal()).getCredentials()).getToken();
     }

    ///BEGIN session     
     @Bean
     public SessionRegistry sessionRegistry() {
        SessionRegistry sessionRegistry = new SessionRegistryImpl();
        return sessionRegistry;
     }


    @Bean
    public RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy registerSessionAuthStr( ) {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy( sessionRegistry( ) );
    }

    // Register HttpSessionEventPublisher
    @Bean
    public static ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }
```

I don't really know what else I should change to make it work, but I believe there has to be something wrong in there. But I think if I can have the Keycloak authentication screen when trying to access my service, this would be alright.

Comment: What about the configuration of "myReal-api", does it have **Valid Redirect URIs** defined?

Comment: I set the "Access type" to ```bearer only```. In this case you don't have to set a Valid Redirect URI so I didn't have to configure that option

Comment: Tooltip near Access Type says: `"Bearer-only" clients are web services that never initiate login`. But you actually trying to initiate login and perform SSO. SSO worked for me with Access Type: confidential and properly set redirect URIs.

Comment: Thanks, I had not noticed that detail. But why do I have no access to my app since I don't have to login ? And I noticed something else, I just commented the line ```bearer-only: true``` from my config, and relauching my app results in a ```Bearer-only applications are not allowed to initiate browser login``` error message. Do I have to uncomment it (considering that if I do, I get a 401 error instead) ?

Comment: So you commented bearer-only in your application, but have you changed Access Type from Keycloak Admin console and set it to confidential (and added URIs)?

Comment: Regarding "why do I have no access". Let me explain my understanding of using 'Bearer-Only'. Let's say you have Service A (some web app) that is accessed by a user from the browser. And you have Service B - some internal service that is only used by service A. In this case 'Bearer Only' will be used by service B, because Service A will be responsible for redirecting the user to Keyclaok for login, and Service A will already have a token and pass it to service B when making requests. Which means service B will never initiate user login. And for service A you should use Access Type: confidential

Comment: I enabled the Spring Security logs and I'm getting these ```Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@631f7b08: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@59b2: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.22.165; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'``` which triggers a ```org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied```. I'm pretty sure it also explains my problem

Comment: To be honest, at this point I'm not sure how to fix that issue

Answer (score 7):

I received the same error, one thing to double check is that `auth-server-url` is the same for the server, and the client getting the token.

I.e. if one is the dns name, and one is the IP address, it will **not authorize**. (in my case I had localhost and 127.0.0.1 so authorization failed)

Server, src/main/resources/application.yml

[image]

Postman/client:

[image]

Comment: After banging my head for few hours, finally I found this answer which worked perfectly. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Hi, a lot of thanks !! this solved my issue.

Comment: I wasted a few hours on this, thanks mate!

Comment: That is it right here. After a couple of hours of hammering the wall. This solved the issue. Thanks.
One would think localhost and 127 are interchangeable. But nope.

Answer (score 3):

This solved my issue.  I was using within a docker container and had to match both to `host.docker.internal`